# How to scroll window contents using Direct2D api?

Tags: gdi, direct3d, direct2d

I would like to scroll window contents in which drawing is performed with  Direct2D api through ID2D1RenderTarget.

In GDI I could create a buffer with CreateCompatibleDC and later scroll its contents with ScrollDC, redraw exposed area and BitBlt the buffer to window.

I cannot see any necessary API in Direct2D to perform the same operations. How can I achieve the same functionality without using GetDC (and GDI), and without using own third buffer?

Answer (score 3):

There is no Scroll API in Direct2D. Your best solution to get hardware accelerated scrolling is to use a 2nd buffer. On the `ID2D1RenderTarget` that you want to scroll, use `CreateCompatibleRenderTarget()` to create an `ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget`  (it's a good idea to cache this guy) with the same pixel size as `ID2D1RenderTarget::GetPixelSize()` and with the same resolution as returned from `ID2D1RenderTarget::GetDpi()`. Then, use `ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget::GetBitmap()` to get the underlying `ID2D1Bitmap`. Next, use `ID2D1Bitmap::CopyFromRenderTarget()` copy the contents with adjustments for the distance you're scrolling. Then copy that bitmap's contents back to the original render target, re-render the uncovered area, and present (via EndDraw).

Comment: You described own third buffer solution, which I want to avoid. It means extra memory and extra bitblt (which can be noticeable on multi monitor setup).

Comment: Yeah I was just pointing out that that's what you'll need to do. There simply is no built-in API for scrolling.

Comment: I have read that one can share a surface between two DirectX apis, I was trying to share a surface between Direct2D rendering to a window and some other where I could scroll contents but without any success.

Comment: If it's hooked up to an ID2D1HwndRenderTarget, have you tried using regular ol' ScrollWindow or ScrollWindowEx? (not ScrollDC) I'd be interested in hearing whether that produces the desired result: the contents are scrolled by hardware if possible, and then the uncovered region is invalidated and only gives you a WM_PAINT for that area.

Comment: Any solution in the end? I'll try just redrawing the contents fast enough w/ the new offset...

Answer (score 3):

You can use translation.

MSDN: To translate a 2-D object is to move the object along the x-axis, the y-axis, or both.

```
m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(20, 10));
```

More details here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756691(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In DXGI 1.2 there is a new `IDXGISwapChain1::Present1` API call with `DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS`
parameter. It contains functionality supporting scrolling window contents.